# Convertir de Chr a Date

Tags: r, date

Tengo un problema tratando de analizar, una base de datos. He cargado un archivo csv, en la columna llamada "Date", la toma como un Chracter, el formato es el siguiente Feb 20 (MMM YY) he intentado esto para pasarlo a fecha:

```
Datos$Date <- as.Date( Datos$Date, format = "%b %y")
```

pero no he tenido éxito, espero poder contar con su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: ¿Los nombres de los meses están en inglés o español? es decir, dice `Jan` o `Ene`?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar completar la fecha con el primer día del mes

```
Datos<-data.frame(Date="Feb 20",stringsAsFactors = F)
Datos$Date <- as.Date( paste0(Datos$Date," 01"), format = "%b %y %d") 
str(Datos)
```

Answer (score 0):

La función `dmy()` del paquete `lubridate` es muy útil en este caso, pero será necesario agregar primero el día manualmente con un `paste()`. Sólo cambio una línea del código que puso @rolando-tamayo .

```r
library(lubridate)

Datos<-data.frame(Date = "Feb 20", stringsAsFactors = F)
Datos$Date <- dmy(paste("01", "Feb 20"))
str(Datos)
```